# Predicting missing data values in a database

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics

I have a database, consisting of a whole bunch of records (around 600,000) where some of the records have certain fields missing. My goal is to find a way to predict what the missing data values should be (so I can fill them in) based on the existing data.

One option I am looking at is clustering - i.e. representing the records that are all complete as points in some space, looking for clusters of points, and then when given a record with missing data values try to find out if there are any clusters that could belong in that are consistent with the existing data values. However this may not be possible because some of the data fields are on a nominal scale (e.g. color) and thus can't be put in order.

Another idea I had is to create some sort of probabilistic model that would predict the data, train it on the existing data, and then use it to extrapolate.

What algorithms are available for doing the above, and is there any freely available software that implements those algorithms (This software is going to be in c# by the way).

Comment: Huge problem. Very dependent on lots of things we cannot predict. Simplest instance: are there any selection biases in which records have missing fields? How do you know? What can you do about it? Are there proxy indicators available? And so on...

Comment: Agreeing with the above comment. There may be some general algorithms an ideas you could use, but you'd have to customizing each of them to your domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dealing with missing values is a methodical question that has to do with the actual meaning of the data.

Several methods you can use (detailed [post on my blog](http://www.developerzen.com/2009/08/14/data-mining-handling-missing-values-the-database/)):

1. **Ignore the data row.** This is usually done when the class label is missing (assuming you data mining goal is classification), or many attributes are missing from the row (not just one). However you'll obviously get poor performance if the percentage of such rows is high
2. **Use a global constant to fill in for missing values.** Like "unknown", "N/A" or minus infinity. This is used because sometimes is just doesnt make sense to try and predict the missing value. For example if you have a DB if, say, college candidates and state of residence is missing for some, filling it in doesn't make much sense...
3. **Use attribute mean**. For example if the average income of a US family is X you can use that value to replace missing income values.
4. **Use attribute mean for all samples belonging to the same class**. Lets say you have a cars pricing DB that, among other things, classifies cars to "Luxury" and "Low budget" and you're dealing with missing values in the cost field. Replacing missing cost of a luxury car with the average cost of all luxury cars is probably more accurate then the value you'd get if you factor in the low budget cars
5. **Use data mining algorithm to predict the value**. The value can be determined using regression, inference based tools using Baysian formalism , decision trees, clustering algorithms used to generate input for step method #4 (K-Mean\Median etc.)
   I'd suggest looking into regression and decision trees first (ID3 tree generation) as they're relatively easy and there are plenty of examples on the net.

As for packages, if you can afford it and you're in the Microsoft world look at SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS for short) that implement most of the mentioned above.

Here are some links to free data minning software packages:

- WEKA - http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/index.html
- ORANGE - http://www.ailab.si/orange
- TANAGRA - http://eric.univ-lyon2.fr/~ricco/tanagra/en/tanagra.html

Although not C# he's a pretty good intro to decision trees and baysian learning (using Ruby): 
http://www.igvita.com/2007/04/16/decision-tree-learning-in-ruby/
http://www.igvita.com/2007/05/23/bayes-classification-in-ruby/

There's also this Ruby library that I find very useful (also for learning purposes):
http://ai4r.rubyforge.org/machineLearning.html

There should be plenty of samples for these algorithms online in any language so I'm sure you'll easily find C# stuff too...

Edited:

Forgot this in my original post. This is a definately MUST HAVE if you're playing with data mining...
Download [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Data Mining Add-ins for Microsoft Office 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=896A493A-2502-4795-94AE-E00632BA6DE7&displaylang=en) (It requires SQL Server Analysis Services - SSAS - which isn't free but you can download a trial).

This will allow you to easily play and try out the different techniques in Excel before you go and implement this stuff yourself. Then again, since you're in the Microsoft ecosystem, you might even decide to go for an SSAS based solution and count on the SQL Server guys to do it for ya :)

Answer (score 7):

This is less of an algorithmic and more of a philosophical and methodological question. There are a few different techniques available to tackle this kind of question. Acock (2005) gives a good introduction to some of the methods. Although it may seem that there is a lot of math/statistics involved (and may seem like a lot of effort), it's worth thinking what would happen if you messed up.

Andrew Gelman's blog is also a good resource, although the search functionality on his blog leaves something to be desired...

Hope this helps.

---

Acock (2005)

http://oregonstate.edu/~acock/growth-curves/working%20with%20missing%20values.pdf

Andrew Gelman's blog

http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~cook/movabletype/mlm/

Answer (score 2):

Predicting missing values is generally considered to be part of data cleansing phase which needs to be done before the data is mined or analyzed further. This is quite prominent in real world data.

Please have a look at this algorithm http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701152

Currently Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services 2008 also comes with algorithms like these http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175312.aspx which help in predictive modelling of attributes.

cheers

Comment: Nice. But the paper seems to make the implicit assumption that there is no selection bias. Or did I miss something?